# What is the rule of boiling hot and freezing cold in a sentence?

Tags: adjectives, compounds

Boiling hot, freezing cold, soaking wet and etc are adjective+adjective. So they are compound adjectives. Am I right? Wiktionary says they are idiomatic but I cannot get what is idiomatic? There is also pouring rain that is verb+noun. What is this compound word called too?

Edit: My teacher says boiling in boiling hot act as an adverb. Also he says pouring rain is a [set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase) in the following example:

I walked home in the pouring rain and I got soaking wet.

Comment: I think that wiki wants to imply that these adjectives are usually used with each other.

Comment: In their [glossary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#idiomatic) they mention the following: *Pertaining or conforming to the mode of expression characteristic of a language. Idioms, collocations and modal verbs are examples of idiomatic language.* I reckon it'd be wise to look up the meanings of words/terms you don't know or know only vaguely.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking about. *Pouring rain* is an idiom.

Comment: They are all idioms, but I think he's asking about two words which mean have similar meanings being collocated together (is that redundant?)

Comment: From NOAD: **idiomatic** (*adj.*) using, containing, or denoting expressions that are natural to a native speaker.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these expressions are idiomatic, but you could also argue that the first word in the pair can be deemed an **intensifier**.

Grammatically speaking, an *intensifier* is used to add force or an emotional boost to a word or phrase. Two common and classic intensifiers are *very* and *really*, as in:

> *That was a really good question!*

The [Grammar Teacher website](http://grammar-teacher.com/adjective-intensifiers/) has a page on adjective intensifiers. The page says:

> Certain adjectives have their own ‘special’ intensifiers which are often used with them.

and it offers these examples:

- *bone dry*
- *brand new*
- *pitch black*
- *wide open*

If *bone dry* is an example of a phrase with an adjective intensifier, it stands to reason that *soaking wet* would be as well. I think *freezing cold* and *boiling hot* would also be good examples, particularly when those expressions are not being used in a scientific sense; for example:

> *It was freezing cold in that movie theater! I wish I had brought a sweater*.